# How to place in the titlepage of a Beamer presentation the subtitle before the title?

Tags: beamer, frame-title

By default, in the titlepage, the subtitle is placed after the title. But for a specific Beamer presentation, I have the need for the subtitle to be placed before the title. Clearly writing \subtitle before \title in the preamble does not work. A forced solution would be to change the font sizes of title and subtitle, so that it looks like their roles are swapped. However, I imagine there must be a better way to do this.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \subtitle{Today we remember \ldots}
    \title{C. F. Gauss (1777-1855)}   
    \author{The author} 
    \date{\today} 
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Carl Friedrich Gauss}
        Some text.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output (only titlepage):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With beamer v3.70 or newer, you could redefine the `title` template like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
    \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \vskip0.25em%
    \fi%       
    \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\subtitle{Today we remember \ldots}
\title{C. F. Gauss (1777-1855)}   
\author{The author} 
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]